# Como deixar um espaço entre o menu e o topo de uma página?

Tags: html, css, webdesign

Gostaria de deixar um pequeno espaço entre a barra de navegação e o menu (aproximadamente 20pxs) sem que o posicionamento da imagem de fundo seja afetado.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/text.css">
        </head>

    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SOBRE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    font-family: arial;
}

/** Background image **/ 

#header {
    background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;

}

nav {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: right;

}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 25px 0 25px 0;

}

nav a {
    color: white;
    padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

Comment: O que vc chama de "_barra de navegação_"?

Answer (score 1):

Vinicius, tudo bem?

Você pode utilizar a propriedade "**padding**" do CSS, como você quer uma distancia entre o menu e o topo da página (com a imagem), você poderia por exemplo, colocar uma "**padding-top**" dentro do seu id "**header**".

Por exemplo:

```
#header {
    background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Lembrando que **"padding"** sempre dará um espaço interno sobre o elemento que você está aplicando, ao contrário do **"margin"**, que dará um espaço externo.

Comment: Entenda mais sobre padding css em https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/propriedade-css-padding.php

Answer (score 1):

Vc pode colocar um `padding-top` no `#header`, isso vai empurrar a `nav` para baixo, mas ainda vai deixar a imagem do `background` colada na barra superior da janela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
}

/** Background image **/

#header {
  background-image: url(https://placecage.com/100/100);
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;

  padding-top: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: right;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px 0 25px 0;

}

nav a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
  text-decoration: none;

}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SOBRE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVIÇOS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTATO</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```